# push notifications will received if app uninstalled and after 1month again installed?

Tags: testing, notifications, push, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

Suppose App installed user registered in app and then uninstalled it, in this scenario push notifications which was to send to that user will receive to him when he install same app after 1 month? or the push notifications will get lapsed of 1 month ? Please help me on this

Answer (score 0):

if the app is not installed, no notifications will be received on the phone.